# Can I use a Clob as a table key (from Java)?

Tags: primary-key, datatypes, java

Following a suggestion made to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540470/how-to-create-a-jdo-datanucleus-key-string-field-of-unknown-size) to store large amounts of text: can one use a [CLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html) as primary key field (i.e., from Java's DataNucleus implementation of JDO)?

I know it is probably a very bad idea to use a CLOB as a key, but I do need to use large text as a key on a one-shot operation.

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you running this against?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple version would be to generate a hash from the CLOB and use this as a key. This key will fit into the allowed key width for your engine (900 SQL Server, 767 InnoDB, 1000 MyISAM etc).

The hash can be generated by the engine as a computed column, trigger, or by some ETL process, or by the application

There is a faint chance of collision ([birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table)) but this would only matter for many records *and* poor choice of hashing algorithm